# How to force truncate all tables(which are all innodb) in a database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I think I get foreign key constraint error when I try to truncate innodb tables. I was not having problems with this when using MyISAM.

Is there an easy way to force truncate all tables? Or should I just make a script to drop the database, create new one and then create the tables from scratch?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

About the FK constraints, you could disable them with next statements -

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
...DML statements
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; -- enable checking
```

Comment: Don't do this because you will get foreign key contraint errors. Use instead `DELETE FROM table`. It will NOT cascade delete every record found in other tables as it's foreign key.

Answer (score 8):

If you have foreign key problems during your operation you can:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE KEYS
```

then do your business, and afterwards re-enable keys with:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENABLE KEYS
```

This techinique is used in MySQL dumps.